# How to find the angle formed by the intersection of three lines forming a triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

Find the angle $x$ as indicated in the figure from below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&15^{\circ}\\
2.&20^{\circ}\\
3.&40^{\circ}\\
4.&30^{\circ}\\
5.&45^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly the requested angle can be found?. Initially I thought it could had been $60^{\circ}$ but on a closer inspection the figure shows it is not formed by the intersection of those lines.

I remember there's an identity which says that the sum of the exterior angles of a triangle add up to $360^{\circ}$.

In this case it would mean that:

$3\alpha+120+180-\alpha=360$

Then $2\alpha=60$

Then $\alpha=30^{\circ}$

But that's how far I went, can someone help me with a better method?. It would be much helpful to use some diagram or drawing as I can find easier how to find that angle. The approach which I intend to look for is relying on euclidean geometry identities.

Answer (score 1):

$$3\alpha + \angle BAD = 180∘$$

By sum of interior angles of a $\triangle$,
$$\angle ABD + 2\alpha + \angle BAD = 180∘$$

Substituting,
$$\angle ABD + 2\alpha + {180∘} - 3\alpha = {180∘}$$

$$\angle ABD - \alpha = 0$$
$$\angle ABD = \alpha$$

Therefore, by congruence of opposite angles,
$$\alpha + x = {60∘}$$

In $\triangle BDC$, by exterior angle equals sum of interior opposite angles,
$$2\alpha = x + \alpha$$

$$x = \alpha$$

Therefore,

$$2\alpha = {60∘} \implies \alpha = {30∘}$$

Therefore,
$$x = {30∘}$$

Comment: Thanks! for that. Its neat and it closely matches with what I intended to do.

Comment: I recommend that you fix the math code in your answer because one line referring to the interior opposite angles is not displaying correctly. Can you fix that?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Thanks for the comment. I have fixed the answer to format that line correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Note also in $\triangle DCB$ you have $2\alpha=\alpha+x$ (the exterior angle is equal to the sum of the two non-adjacent interior angles), so $x=\alpha=30^\circ$.

It really doesn't help that the sketch is quite far off the mark, e.g. the angle $\alpha$ on the image is way bigger than $30^\circ$, $\angle CDB=120^\circ$ should be obtuse but is drawn as acute, etc.

Comment: Btw I didn't noted the identity you have noted. However I believe that the angle $\angle \alpha$ might not be accurate but is somewhat closer to $30^{\circ}$ while you're right $\angle CDB$ is $120^{\circ}$ and it doesn't seem to match with what the image portrays. Whoever build this problem probably did not took into consideration that thing.